# application behind a restful Webservice

Tags: java, rest

I really try to avoid asking questions like this and try to read instead, but the time is expanding and i have no solution.

I have implemented an Application which has 2 server and 1 client which is the panel of the application . the panel normally gives introductions to the 2 servers.

now we have to implement a central point, which gets introductions via rest.

but i dont understand how to get a connection between my stateless webservice and my stateful application.

it should be like this:
dashboard->webservice->myapplication

thanks for everyone who can help

Comment: sorry i mean instruction :)

Comment: You can [edit] your question.